# Не работает inline-block для IE 8. Как сделать?

Tags: inline, html, internet-explorer, css

**Здравствуйте!**

Не обходимо разместить блоки DIV в строчку, использую правило CSS **inline-block**. Для **IE 8** оно не работает. Вписал условный комментарий для **IE 8**, чтобы использовал **inline** - Эффекта нет, *хотя везде пишут, что это помагает.* Помогите кто может!

Код такой:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Документ Без Имени</title>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
#chekmate{
  zoom:1;
  display:inline;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
#chekmate {
display:inline-block;
width:80px;
height:40px;
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='chekmate'><a href='http://фрунзе.топ-ярус.рф/view_kvart_frunze.php?id=%s'>
<span style='display:block; width:78px; height:19px; border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold;'>%s</span>
<span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span><span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 7px 0 10px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span></a></div>

</div>
<div id='chekmate'><a href='http://фрунзе.топ-ярус.рф/view_kvart_frunze.php?id=%s'>
<span style='display:block; width:78px; height:19px; border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold;'>%s</span>
<span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span><span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 7px 0 10px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span></a></div>

</div>
<div id='chekmate'><a href='http://фрунзе.топ-ярус.рф/view_kvart_frunze.php?id=%s'>
<span style='display:block; width:78px; height:19px; border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold;'>%s</span>
<span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span><span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 7px 0 10px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span></a></div>

</div>
<div id='chekmate'><a href='http://фрунзе.топ-ярус.рф/view_kvart_frunze.php?id=%s'>
<span style='display:block; width:78px; height:19px; border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold;'>%s</span>
<span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span><span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 7px 0 10px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span></a></div>

</div>
<div id='chekmate'><a href='http://фрунзе.топ-ярус.рф/view_kvart_frunze.php?id=%s'>
<span style='display:block; width:78px; height:19px; border:1px solid black; font-weight:bold;'>%s</span>
<span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span><span style='border:1px solid black; padding: 0 7px 0 10px; border-top: 2px;'>%s</span></a></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы бы с разметкой разобрались для начала. Почему у вас после каждого блока

```
<div id='chekmate'> ... </div>
```

еще один закрывающий тег < /div> ?

P.S. Для IE8+ - никакие условные коментарии и отдельные фиксы для **inline-block** и **inline** не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо буду повнимательнее!